# Searching ListView That Uses LayoutInflater In Android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

Hello guys i am trying to add a search functionality in my activity that uses a listView to show vehicle information. I tried many solution but none work for me.

Actually i have added a textView in VehicleActivity & i want to filter the content of my listView when user type something in textView.

this the code of VehicleActivity

```
 public class VehicleActivity extends Activity
{
        //The PlaceHolder For The View's
    ListView listView;
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;


    //Static Variable For Passing The VehicleActivity Context To SessionExpired()
    public static Context mContext;

    //public ImageView    img_arrow;
    public int context_menu_index;

    //Alert DialogBox
    public AlertDialog AltDialog;
    public boolean CDialog_value = false;       //Used when command of immoblize & De-Imoblize use fired

    //Exception Handling
    static PostException PstExp;

    //Text View
    EditText editsearch;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        try
        {
            Log.d("VA OnC", "Before Super");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mContext = getBaseContext();
            setTitleBar();              //Setting The Title Bar

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_vehicle);      //Passing The XML Layout

            //Getting Infromation From Parent Activity
            Intent intent_veh       = getIntent();
            User_ID                 = intent_veh.getIntExtra("UID", 0);                             //UserId
            session_key             = intent_veh.getStringExtra("Key");                             //Session Key
            permissions             = new int [(intent_veh.getIntArrayExtra("Rights")).length];     //Permissions Length
            permissions             = intent_veh.getIntArrayExtra("Rights");                        //Permissions Assignment


            //To Overwrite The Last Value Of The Variables
            EmptyActivity  = false;
            //Initializing GetVehicleList Object
            obj_GVL   = new    GetVehicleList(VehicleActivity.this, User_ID, session_key);

            //Calling The Method That Will Fetch Information From Server
            obj_GVL.getVehicleInfo();

            Log.d("VA ", "Before EA Check");
            if( EmptyActivity  == false )
            {
                //Passing XML layout To ListView
                Log.d("VA ", "Before listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view)");
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
                Log.d("VA ", "Before listView.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this))");

                mAdapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);
                listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
                listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                //listView.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));

                //Search Box Code Start
                editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

                //Search Box Code End

                Log.d("VA ", "Before listView.setOnItemClickListener()");
                Log.d("VA ", "Before VehicleList.Location[0] =");
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e)
        {
            //Some Code
        }
        catch(Error e2) 
        {
            //Some Code
        }
    } 

    //Some code 

    }
```

This is code of My Adapter which is part of Vehicle Activity

```
//Passing Actual Data To PlaceHolder Of ListView
    private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) 
        {
            //mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() 
        {
            return VehicleList.Vehicle_ID.length;
            //return GetVehicleList.ID.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {   
            ViewHolder holder;
            try
            {
               if (convertView == null) 
               {
                     mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.three_col_row, null);

                      holder = new ViewHolder();

                      holder.text1 = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.imei);
                      holder.text2 = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
                      holder.text3 = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
                      holder.text4 = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.speed);
                      holder.text5 = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                      holder.img_option = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_arrow);

                      convertView.setTag(holder);

                     holder.img_option.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                     {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                          VehicleActivity.this.registerForContextMenu(listView);                                           
                          VehicleActivity.this.openContextMenu(listView);


                          VehicleActivity.this.context_menu_index = VehicleActivity.this.listView.getPositionForView(v);

                        }
                    });

               }  
               else 
               {
                     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
               }

               holder.img_option.setFocusable(true);
               holder.img_option.setClickable(true);
               holder.img_option.setTag(holder);

                //Setting The Font Style
               holder.text1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
               holder.text2.setTypeface(null,  Typeface.ITALIC);  

                //Passing The Actual Values To TextViews
               holder. text1.setText("ID: "       +VehicleList.IMEI[position]);
               holder.text2.setText("Status: "   +VehicleList.Status[position]);
               holder.text3.setText("Location: " +VehicleList.Location[position]);
               holder.text4.setText("Speed: "   +VehicleList.Speed[position]);
               holder.text5.setText("Date: " +VehicleList.Date[position]);

               convertView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 ? Color.parseColor("#eaeaea") : Color.parseColor("#d3e3f3"));
            }
            catch( Exception e)
            {
                PstExp = new PostException("VA.EA.GETVEW Ln:830",                                                                   //Block
                           (e.getMessage() == null)? "null": "Android App VA.EA.GETVEW() \n"+e.getMessage().toString(),             //Message
                        (e.getStackTrace() == null)? "null": "Android App VA.EA.GETVEW() \n"+e.getStackTrace().toString(),          //Stack Trace
                             (e.getCause() == null)? "null": "Android App VA.EA.GETVEW() \n"+e.getCause().toString()        );      //Inner Exception
            }
            catch(Error e2) 
            {
                PstExp = new PostException("VA.EA.GETVEW Ln:837",                                                                   //Block
                       (e2.getMessage() == null)? "null": "Android App VA.EA.GETVEW() \n"+e2.getMessage().toString(),               //Message
                    (e2.getStackTrace() == null)? "null": "Android App VA.EA.GETVEW() \n"+e2.getStackTrace().toString(),            //Stack Trace
                         (e2.getCause() == null)? "null": "Android App VA.EA.GETVEW() \n"+e2.getCause().toString()      );          //Inner Exception
            }

          return convertView;
        }

        public class ViewHolder 
        {
            TextView text1;
            TextView text2;
            TextView text3;
            TextView text4;
            TextView text5;
            ImageView img_option;
        }


    }
```

this the code of VehicleList

```
public class VehicleList 
{
public static int[] Vehicle_ID;

public static String[] IMEI; 
public static String[] Status; 
public static String[] Location;

public static String[] Speed; 
public static String[] Date;

public static Double[] Latitude;
public static Double[] Longitude;

String error="", msg="";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From your question, what I have understood is, you need to implement search functionality when you enter the text in **Search edit box**. So the above code is working perfectly i guess(at least initially, when the activity is loaded for the first time). In your case you need to add **textChangeListener** for the **edit text box** as follows.

```
editsearch.addTextChangedListener(this); 

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

Move these lines in to a method,

```
mAdapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

and call the method inside

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help & now i am confuse in implement the Filterable interface.